# NSString Date to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

`NSString Date` to `NSDate` in `iOS` not displaying proper details.
I have `NSString date` is :

```
NSString *strFinal = @"2016-10-20 12:00:00";
```

I am following below method to convert NSString to NSDate

```
  NSString *strFinal = @"2016-10-20 12:00:00";


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strFinal];
```

and my out put is :

> string date is : 2016-10-20 12:00:00
>   NSDate is: 2016-10-19 18:30:00
>   +0000

it generates different date and different format from `NSString` i want the same `NSDate`.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];`

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: Hello Bhavin,
Thanks for reply. i got this i need to use UTC but i am still getting  +0000 after NSDate convertion. Can we remove this also?

Comment: why you are doing this.    NSLog(@"date %@",dateFromString);
if you will do this then get date 2016-01-19 18:30:00 +0000. this is right

Comment: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];` output: `2016-10-20 12:00:00 +0000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with time zone and it can be solved by adding this line of code:

```
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

You can also set `TimeZone` by:

```
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

OR

[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

OR

[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
```